# JSP file is served as plain/text, when TOMCAT is behind an APACHE server

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat

I'm running in a strange problem. I have a project based on MAVEN. When I run the project directly from my computer for testing it, using mvn tomcat7:run, my website display is correct. When I upload it to my distant Tomcat server, that is accessed through the JK Apache Tomcat connector, the JSP page is served as a text file. In response headers, I can see `Content-Type:text/plain`which is almost strange, and I'm suspecting the Apache server is adding it because of some erroneous configuration.

Any idea where to look, to fix this problem ?